# C programming and OpenCV (How to read an image from a file and load it for further processing in openCv)

Tags: c, file, opencv

I have created a file in C which contains the filemanes of images. The code is given below ("Leaves" is a dataset of images. I am storing the image names in a file):

```
FILE *fp;

system("dir /B D:\\opencvprojects\\platphenotypeFinal\\platphenotypeFinal\\Leaves > file.txt");
```

file.txt looks like this:

```
1001.jpg

1002.jpg

1003.jpg

1004.jpg

1005.jpg

1006.jpg

1007.jpg
```

Now I want to read each image from the file, do the background subtraction in openCV and save the results for all these images in another file.

```
OriginalImage=cvLoadImage("Leaves\\1007.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

I know how to read a single image (using the above code), but I want to automatically read each image of the file, do the processing, and save the result in another file, and the process continues in a loop until all images are taken care of.Thus, an output file will be generated containing the file names (same as the input file names) of binary images.

Your help will be very much appreciated.

```
int main()
{
   CvMoments moments;

   CvMemStorage *connectedCompStorage = cvCreateMemStorage (0);

   CvSeq *temp = NULL;                              //used to loop through contour perimeter checking
   CvSeq *connectedComp = NULL;           

   FILE *fp;
   char buffer[9];

   system("dir /B D:\\opencvprojects\\platphenotypeFinal\\platphenotypeFinal\\Leaves > file.txt");
   fp = fopen ("file.txt", "r+");

   OriginalImage = cvLoadImage("Leaves\\1108.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
}
```

Comment: sorry, but **no, sorry**. C is no more a valid option with opencv in 2015. darn that dream, but you'll **have** to use c++ now..

Comment: Could you please help me with the C++ code for this?

Comment: please post what you have so far and tell us how it fails

Comment: file.txt is created successfully with the filenames of the images as mentioned above. But, I do not know how to access the file names in CvloadImage automatically from the file.txt. Presently I am using a single image (I.e., "Leaves \\1108.jpg") which works correctly. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

opencv has a nice glob function to read a whole directory:

(and please, do **not** use opencv's C-api !)

```
vector<String> files;
glob("D:\\opencvprojects\\platphenotypeFinal\\platphenotypeFinal\\Leaves\*.jpg", files);

for (size_t i=0; i<files.size(); i++)
{
    Mat m = imread(files[i]);
    // process image
}
```

Comment: whats the purpose of the string "files"?